# react classNames using two conditional classes

Tags: reactjs

I have a div as following:

```
<div className={classNames("div-one",
    {"half-width": this.state.showRegistration || this.state.showLogin})}>
</div>
```

What I want is: on `!this.state.showRegistration || !this.state.showLogin` this condition I want append "full-width" class to div-one instead of "half-width"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `className={'div-one ${!this.state.showRegistration || !this.state.showLogin ? 'half-width' : '''}`

Comment: @elmeister Is one right bracket missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!this.state.showRegistration || !this.state.showLogin
```

is not the negation of

```
this.state.showRegistration || this.state.showLogin
```

The proper negation would be `!this.state.showRegistration && !this.state.showLogin`.

But I guess you want something like this:

```
const registrationOrLogin = this.state.showRegistration || this.state.showLogin;

const classes = classNames("div-one", {
    "half-width": registrationOrLogin,
    "full-width": !registrationOrLogin
})

<div className={classes}}>
</div>
```

or

```
const classes = `div-one ${registrationOrLogin ? "half-width" : "full-width"}`;
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that `classNames` is actually an npm module you have to install to get your code example to work https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: Thanks for correcting my negation, that worked. Actually in my logic I don't want to show either login or registration rather in basic state it shows div-one with full-width and when login or registration is opened then it shows div-one with half-width

Answer (score 0):

```
const resultClass = {this.state.showRegistration || this.state.showLogin ? 'half-width' : 'full-width'};
<div className={classNames("div-one",
    [resultClass]: true }>
</div>
```